# How to get users from Active Directory using Unboundid LDAP SDK?

Tags: active-directory, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to get users from Active Directory.
According to many places include MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

the correct query is this `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`.

Unfortunately, I was not able to create the query using Unboundid filters.

I have created the following filters:

```
Filter categoryFilter = Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectCategory","Person");
Filter objectFilter = Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass","user");
Filter searchFilter = Filter.createANDFilter(objectFilter, categoryFilter);
```

It does not return results.
When I looked into objectCategory of LDAP object I have found that it looks like the following:

`CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=…,DC=com`

Therefore I have changed categoryFilter to the following:

```
Filter categoryFilter = Filter.createSubstringFilter("objectCategory", null, new String[]{"Person"}, null);
```

Unfortunately, I still do not get results.

Then I used the categoryFilter with the full objectCategory name:

```
Filter categoryFilter = Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectCategory","CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=…,DC=com");
```

Only in the last case I get results.

How to make the filter more generic?
How to obtain the full objectCategory name from Active Directory?

I need to obtain `CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=…,DC=com` for any Active Directory while I know that the `objectCategory` is `Person`.

Do you know other way to create filters for the query `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`?

**Solution**

(not mine therefore do not want to put in the answer)

I have created filter using the following string `(sAMAccountType=805306368)` and it works perfect:

```
Filter searchFilter =  Filter.create("(sAMAccountType=805306368)");
```

Source: http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllUsers